# pybliometrics - Is there a limit to the amount of records retrieved through get_coauthors()?

Tags: scopus, pybliometrics

I am using the AuthorRetrieval class to get information from Scopus author records, including their co-authors. I have noticed that the `get_coauthors()` function only retrieves a maximum of 160 co-authors, even when there are many more co-authors.

```
import pybliometrics
from pybliometrics.scopus import AuthorRetrieval
import pandas as pd

print(pybliometrics.__version__)

>> 2.7.0

au = AuthorRetrieval(7101875313)
co_au = au.get_coauthors()
len(co_au)

>> 160

au = AuthorRetrieval(35325278500)
co_au = au.get_coauthors()
len(co_au)

>> 160
```

The records for these authors on scopus.com indicate that they both have 5000+ associated co-authors.

Is there a limit to the amount of co-authors that we can pull from the Scopus API, or from this function in pybliometrics AuthoRetrieval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that 160 is the limit of the get_coauthors() function

Comment: I notice that even on scopus.com there is a limit of 150 co-authors. Take Simon I. Hay (https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId=7101875313&origin=resultslist). Scopus lists the author as having 6404 co-authors, but displays this message:

`About co-authors
A maximum of 150 co-authors can be displayed. To see the whole list and more author information: 
view list in search results format.`

And then in the search results format, an error message says that only 150 can be displayed. Which Scopus API can provide us with the full set of co-authors?

Comment: Good to know, will add this to the documentation